# Column.isNull() vs. not(Column.isNotNull())

Tags: apache-spark

Here is my sample code that reads from a single cassandra table called "test." I achieve this in a couple of different ways which, however, should be logically identical. Indeed, the condition Column.isNull() should be equivalent to not(Column.isNotNull()).

```
    // scenario 1
    Dataset<Row> data = session.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").option("keyspace", "testkeyspace").option("table", "test").load();
    Column expr = data.col("col1").isNull();
    data = data.filter(expr);
    List<Row> rows = data.collectAsList();
    System.out.println("Number of rows when expression is 'isNull()': " + rows.size());

    // scenario 2
    data = session.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").option("keyspace", "testkeyspace").option("table", "test").load();
    expr = not(data.col("col1").isNotNull());
    data = data.filter(expr);
    rows = data.collectAsList();
    System.out.println("Number of rows when expression is 'not(isNotNull())': " + rows.size());
```

However, I am getting completely different results:

Number of rows when expression is 'isNull()': 336

Number of rows when expression is 'not(isNotNull())': 0

Can anybody please explain what I am possibly doing wrong?
I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. This issue did exist in 2.1.0 (that I was using), but it was fixed in 2.1.1.